# Is there a database of tunes searchable by interval?

Tags: intervals, melody

It's a common technique to use familiar tunes to remind ourselves how intervals sound.

Recently in a zoom rehearsal we were talking about octave leaps and between us came up with the common **octave reminder** tunes of **Somewhere over the Rainbow** and **Singin' in the rain**. But someone then suggested **Starman** which was a great suggestion. I wondered if there was any database of tunes searchable on interval, to generate a larger list of candidate reminder tunes.

I know there's the Parsons code database, but that stores melodic *contour*; for each successive note in the tune you write down whether the note is a Repeat of the last note or the pitch moves Up or Down. This R/U/D representation doesn't record the *size* of any pitch interval.

Currently the only way I know of creating a list of tunes containing a particular interval is by  racking my brain (which is not a systematic process).

Comment: Regarding the above duplicate proposal: see in particular the answer by Matthew Reed, which links to a website offering a substantial list.

Comment: This is not a duplicate and doesn't answer the question. Every tune contains far more than a single interval. I'd like to able to search and get a list of *every* tune containing the named interval *anywhere at all*. So search for descending major third would give a match for "Do a deer" even though "Do a deer" is listed amongst the tunes that remind us what a rising second sounds like.

Comment: I see. The source of the confusion is that the initial focus of your question is on using intervals for song recognition, and the examples use initial intervals. The general question you're trying to ask doesn't come across well. Try rewriting the question to ignore the song identification part, and just focus on asking about a database that stores song information intervallically. (However, I would still vote to close as off topic, since it's a resource request. Maybe the chat room?)